# How can I read strings into an array of strings from a file?

Tags: java, arrays

So I'm trying to read the first 100 strings, which are words into an array of 100 Strings. and while doing that I'm trying to set each corresponding integer in an array of integers to 1, so counting each word the first time its read.

It's reading a book, 100 words at a time, and counting those words. So far I have this, how would I just make a switch statement of 100 cases?

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
package program6;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program6 {
static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
static String input;
String[] StringArray = new String[100];
int[] IntArray = new int[100];
String filename = "myths.txt";
String stringnumber;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
```

Comment: In other words, so far you don't have anything.

Comment: You might want to reconsider your approach to tallying word occurrences assuming that's the goal. Check out the HashMap class.

Comment: As others have pointed out, you don't need to read words in 100 at a time if you use a HashMap class. Please refer to the [HashMap documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

Comment: Thank you for the link, we haven't learned about HashMap's yet, but I'll read up on it.

Comment: I am not saying to choose my answer, but if one of the submitted answers solved your problem, you should accept it. Also, if you found something that solved the issue yourself, you should submit a link to it as an answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 2):

```
HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap();
public void count(String file){
    Scanner in = null;
    try{
        in = new Scanner(new File(file));
    }catch(IOException ex){

    }
    String val = in.next();
    for(String currentKey : map.keySet()){
        if(map.containsKey(val)){
            map.put(currentKey,map.get(currentKey)+1);
        }else{
            map.put(val,1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Map<String, Integer> record = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for(String temp: StringArray){
        if(record.containsKey(temp)){
            Integer num = record.get(temp) + 1;
            record.put(temp, num);
        }
        else{
            record.put(temp, 1);
        }
    }
```